Unable to run yarn dlx
I've got a Next.js v14.2.4 project using Yarn PnP. When I attempt to add the VSCode SDK or run doctor it fails:

Everything else is working--I can run yarn install and yarn dev without issue. But it doesn't make sense why I'm getting a permissions error accessing a Temp folder under my own profile. Any ideas?

It is likely the project you're using has the .yarnrc.yml file as read-only; potentially because it uses projen. Making the .yarnrc.yml file in your project mutable should allow yarn dlx to work.
